# Where can I find a repository for older unsupported releases?

Tags: repository, mirrors, release-management

I remember I saw a apt mirror somewhere containing older distributions but I cannot find it anymore. Does anybody know where to find it?

Answer (score 14):

ok I found it

- releases: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/
- packages: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

See also:

- [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release?rq=1)